# Naming of methods for evaluating a condition

Tags: java, naming-conventions

The following methods are implemented in an abstract base class, that is extended by many subclasses:

```
public final void doSomething() {
    if( hasBehavior1() ) {
        // special behavior 
    }

    if( hasBehavior2() ) {
        // special behavior 
    }

    // do other things
}

protected abstract boolean hasBehavior1();
protected abstract boolean hasBehavior2();
```

How should I name these methods `hasBehaviorX()` for the cases that the special behavior is

- to encrypt some data?
- to ignore an error?
- to check for correctness?

The special behavior is too easy to use a different implementation pattern like the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), so I'm really looking for some useful naming conventions here.

Comment: How about `canXxxx()` instead of `hasXxxx()`?

Comment: How about using the Java Code Convention? isEncrypted(), isIgnorred(), isCorrect()? On the other hand, shouldn't you use polymorphism here?

Comment: 'isEncrypted()' is wrong, because it is *not* encrypted but instead the base class should include an encryption step in its algorithm.

Comment: 'isEncryptable()' is also wrong, because it does not make clear that the algorithm must include an encryption step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to express the special behavior by using the java conventions for boolean members with the verb in its present progressive form:

```
isEncrypting()
isIgnoringError()
isCheckingForCorrectness()
```

Answer (score 0):

for checking correctness

```
isCorrect()
```

to ignore error

```
isErrorIgnored()
```

for encrypted data

```
isEncrypted()
```

Comment: This would be the standard way for boolean javabean getters. But it sounds wrong if I ask an object 'isCorrect()' in the meaning of "shall this subclass check for correctness?". If this method returns false, it does not mean that it's not correct.

Comment: well in that case how about canCorrect()?

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead writing no-op methods :

```
protected boolean doBehavior1() {}
protected boolean doBehavior2() {}
```

That are implemented in subclasses as required. That way you can defer processing to subclasses without needing to interrogate whether those subclasses need to do it.